# ArgumentError in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm making edit object form with Angularjs and Ruby on Rails 4 is my backend.
I got following error and don't see proper way to debug it:

```
Started PUT "/albums/52109834e9c88c3292000001" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-24 17:24:37 +0400
Overwriting existing field email.
Processing by AlbumsController#update as JSON
Parameters: {"_id"=>{}, "title"=>"Sacred Circuits"}
MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=aggregator_front_development collection=users selector={"$query"=>{"_id"=>"520bd6cbe9c88ca789000001"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.7932ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 63ms

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)):
  app/controllers/albums_controller.rb:18:in `update'
```

Line 18 is update function, which has no arguments. I'm sending object from Angularjs form to update it.
**albums_controller.rb:**

```
class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
respond_to :json, :js

def index
    respond_with Album.all
end

def show
    respond_with Album.find(params[:id])

end

def create
    respond_with Album.create(params[:album])
end

def update
    respond_with Album.update(params[:id],params[:album])
end

def destroy
    respond_with Album.destroy(params[:id])
end

private
def album_params
        params.require(:album).permit(:title)
end

end
```

I understand, that ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)) means, but don't know where to look for real arguments send. 
How to debug this situation?

Comment: The problem is you are not sending an `album` as a json object but just an `id` and a `title`. Can you show us the angular code responsible for the `$http.put`?

Comment: Actually i cropped full body of json. It consists _id, title and album with same params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In update action, update is an instance method to update attributes of active_record instance. It accepts only one arguement. But you are passing 2 parameters here. That's why its generating error.

The better way is to first find the album record and then update it. Try this code in update action.

```
.......
def update
  @album = Album.find(params[:id])   #id or whatever key in which you are getting album id
  @album.update(album_params)        #Use strong parameters while doing mass assignment
  ....
end
.......
```

Comment: Object is not saved, due to empty "_id"=>{} in my query from Angular, but that's another story.